# Element width expands as height increases

Tags: css, position, css-float

I used CSS **:before** and **:after** to create a paper like layout with a div. It's fine but the width increases as the height increases. I've tried **max-width** but to no avail. Any ideas on how this can be prevented.

**HTML**

```
<div class="rack"></div><!-- End Rack -->
```

**CSS**

```
.rack {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #7FAE68;
    margin: -255px 0 100px 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: 9999;
    transform:rotate(1deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(1deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(1deg);
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
 .rack::before {
 content: "";
 background:  #E1BB70;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -2;
 transform:rotate(1deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(1deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(1deg);
 float: left;
 left: 0%;
}
 .rack::after {
 content: "";
 background: #E5E8EC;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 transform:rotate(-1deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-1deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-1deg);
 border: solid 1px #ddd;
 left: 0%;
}
```

**Before height increase**
[image]

**After height increase**
[image]

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sleek/npGy8/16/)

Double the content in the fiddle to witness the problem.

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Comment: A jsFiddle would be great :)

Comment: @JamesHunt it's dynamically generated.The DIV in question is the one give. Except if you'd like me to give you the link to the website proper

Comment: That would be lovely, thank you Dz1.

Comment: The link is http://webdesignsharepoint.com/create-a-website-part3/  Switch between pages to see the difference.

Comment: I think the problem is the rotation. As the div gets taller, the effect of a 1 degree rotation becomes more severe.

Comment: As a [**related question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557655/stack-a-relative-div-on-an-absolute-div) you posted later was solved, I wonder whether this one still needs an answer?

Comment: @frank conjin yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css to every class:

```
box-sizing:border-box
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/npGy8/31/

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry that didn't do it.