# Stack a relative DIV on an absolute DIV

Tags: css, css-float, z-index

As I try to solve the problem that led to this my unsolved unsolved [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524108/element-width-expands-as-height-increases), I decided to bring up the **Green DIV** to the front since the content doesn't bleed off of it.

**Structure**

1. Green paper: Main DIV.rack
2. Orange and Gray paper: inserted via CSS **:before** and **:after**

**HTML**

```
<div class="rack">
 Content 
</div><!-- End Rack -->
```

**CSS**

```
.rack {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #7FAE68;
    margin: 155px 0 100px 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: 9999;
    transform:rotate(1deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(1deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(1deg);
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
 .rack::before {
 content: "";
 background:  #E1BB70;
position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -2;
 transform:rotate(1deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(1deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(1deg);
 float: left;
 left: 0%;
}
 .rack::after {
 content: "";
 background: #E5E8EC;
position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 transform:rotate(-1deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(-1deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-1deg);
 border: solid 1px #ddd;
 left: 0%;
   top: 0;
}
```

**Note**
If you look at the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sleek/npGy8/16/), you'll see that the content doesn't bleed beyond the main DIV(gree paper) no matter the height. Since that's that's the case, my best bet would be to bring the green DIV to the top. There's nothing I haven't tried to no avail. Any help on how this can be achieved.

**This image shows that the content(sidebar for example) is still within green(main)DIV.**[image]

Comment: Why do you have a `position:absolute` and a `float` in the same rule?

Comment: @Palpatim I'll take it off but that doens't affect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interested question.

This image from this [awesome post](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/) will make you understand more about layer stack of pseudo elements:

[image: pseudo elements layers stack]

then you will realize that your requirement is impossible.

Anyways, I created some thing looks similar to your need, using the `box-shadow` to make another "stack". See the fiddle.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trungdq88/mMX27/)

Answer (score 1):

Previous poster is quite correct.  The elements created using `:before`, `:after`, and `content` are children of the `.rack` and `z-index` applied to them is not global, but operates within their relatively positioned parent.  That's why you cannot move these behind the `.rack`.  One solution is to wrap the content in a div and use `:before` and `:after` on the wrapper div.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/73Fyk/1/.

One caveat.  The way to stack the `:before` and `:after` elements behind the `.rack` is not to position the `.rack` relatively.  Then, the absolutely placed `:before` and `:after` are positioned, in this case, within the `body` can be easily moved behind the `.rack`.  I do not like this latter approach.  It is much better to keep the related entities together and to just add a tiny hair of markup to wrap the content and to roll from there.

Answer (score 1):

"There's nothing I haven't tried. Any help on how this can be achieved."

Why not just use nested divs? Works just as well, and the code is much more intuitive. Demo here: http://jsbin.com/vizer/1/edit?html,output.

And this is the used code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo Stacked Paper</title>
<style>
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
    font: normal 1.3em Verdana;
    padding: 75px;              /* for the demo */
    background-color: white;    /* for the JSBin demo */
}
.rackGrandParent {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 200px;
    transform:rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(2deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);
}
.rackParent {
    background-color: gold;
    transform:rotate(-4deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-4deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);
}
.rack {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    transform:rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(2deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="rackGrandParent">
        <div class="rackParent">
            <div class="rack">Mauris eu lacus ac nunc tincidunt vehicula. Donec congue, ligula quis vehicula pellentesque, nisi lacus sodales elit, quis elementum nunc risus non ligula. Maecenas eget bibendum ante. Sed bibendum lectus sodales faucibus mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis vel dolor quis metus facilisis dignissim. Suspendisse erat nibh, mollis nec pellentesque id, mattis eu purus. Quisque a nulla pretium, dignissim lectus at, tempor ipsum. Integer quis arcu leo. Maecenas feugiat, nisi viverra mattis pulvinar, urna nulla porttitor orci, vitae condimentum velit nisi sed turpis.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```